# Java EE tutorial, cannot access "userBirthday" input Date

Tags: java, html, reference, enterprise

When doing the firstcup-war tutorial for Java EE http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/firstcup/doc/web-application005.htm  The error message is not shown because it cannot select the right html element. I have the following code:

```
    <fc:inputDate id="userBirthday" date="#{dukesBDay.yourBD}" />
      <h:outputText value=" #{bundle.Pattern}"/>
      <p/>
      <h:commandButton value="#{bundle.Submit}" action="#{dukesBDay.processBirthday}"/>
      <p/>
      <h:message for="userBirthday" style="color:red"/>
```

When looking at the source code in the browser I see that the name tag is actually "`j_idt6:userBirthday:j_idt16`". So if I change the last line of the above posted code to:

```
        <h:message for="j_idt6:userBirthday:j_idt16" style="color:red"/>
```

It works again. Why does Java EE append `j_idt6` and `j_idt16` at the beginning and end of the name tag. And Why is the code in the tutorial not working. What can I do to make it work, without having to check the source code, what the actual tag name looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final ID for the inputDate will be generated in the following format:   **formID:ComponentId:InternalComponentId**

Your **form** has **no ID**, so that a unique id will be generated.
Your **inputDate** component has the ID **"userBirthday"**.
Your internal **inputText** has **no ID**, so that a unique id will be generated.

But you can avoid this by defining IDs for each component.

> **inputDate.xhtml:**
>     `<h:inputText id="inputDateId" value="#{cc.attrs.date}">`
>
> **greeting.xhtml:**
>     `<h:form id="greetingFormId">
>        ...
>        <fc:inputDate id="userBirthdayId" date="#{dukesBDay.yourBD}" />
>        ...
>        <h:message for="greetingFormId:userBirthdayId:inputDateId" style="color:red"/>`

Then you will get an error message like the following:

> greetingFormId:userBirthdayId:inputDateId: '23.12.2001' konnte nicht als Datum interpretiert werden. Beispiel: 05/06/2014